# Get all username of a domain using gdata in AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gdata, google-provisioning-api

I have just began to learn AppEngine with python and in my project I'm building an application in which I need to retrieve all users of my domain.

I used `RetrieveAllOrgUsers` and `RetrieveAllUsers` to get users of my domain, but both of them crash when I deploy the application on my AppEngine account. I get the error `deadlineexceeded`.

Could someone please help me to resolve this issue? I guess maybe I need to use tasks, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

You should spend some time on reading about the limitations of the platform you are using.

Do you understand why/what a DeadelinExceededError means.

That should be you starting point.

Also have a look at the stack trace in the log, and you will see where in you code the error has occurred.

Basically you have a limited amount of time to do things in front end requests.  If you exceed that time , then you will get this error  (there are other reasons) .

I assume your using the provisioning api, and that could be something that takes some serious time.  There are other limits you will need to contend with, such as those around URLFetch as well.

Tasks will more than likely be your solution, but you should try and understand why before embarking on that.

Have a read of https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred which is a easy path into tasks using deferred.